How to move camera in matter.js world?
I am making a RTS game in matter.js, similar to starcraft. One thing I want to implement is panning around with viewports.
I created the canvas and the world
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    //element: document.body,
    canvas: canvas,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        width: 650,
        height: 600,
        hasBounds: true,
        wireframes: false, // required for images
        background: 'green'//'transparent'
    }
});

canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

Note that I have the canvas dimensions smaller than the world dimensions. This is because the canvas dimensions represents the viewport, and the world dimensions represent the actual game dimensions.
I'm running into an issue when I want to set the viewport though. It seems to be scaling it wrong.
    Render.lookAt(render, [{
        "min": {
            "x": 50,
            "y": 0
        },
        "max": {
            "x": 600,
            "y": 600
        }
    }]);

I'm not sure how LookAt works, but its showing me a much smaller part of the game stretched into the canvas. I am trying to for example show the viewport at x=50, y=0, width=600, height=600. This is basically the viewport moved to the right most.
The goal is for game room to be large rectangle, and viewport to be smaller rectangle.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks

It'd be easier to help with a runnable [mcve], preferably a stack snippet. Here's an example of a stack snippet with Matter.js, which incidentally uses a viewport but without the internal renderer, which is for prototyping purposes only (it's also a pretty involved/complex example; for a question, the code should be kept simpler). See also https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#views.

Related: How can I move camera in matter.js

Cross-posted to GitHub: https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1287
